# How to vectorize two nested for loops using numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, iteration, vectorization

I would like to vectorize part of my code below. Specifically the two for loops that iterate from a `range(0,n)`. If anything I could just vectorize the `j` loop because when I include it in my operations the run time exceeds 10 minutes.

I was thinking that for the exponential part that is called wavea and waveb, to do something with `np.reshape` and then subtract these so I can just input them on the exponential function but that will give me a matrix and I am not sure how to treat it.

```py
epsilon = 0.15
def delta(x):
    
    # Definining the delta dirac function as a Lorentzian distribution 
    # with a width epsilon
    
    return (1/np.pi)*(epsilon)/(epsilon**2+x**2)
```

```py
# Doing it inefficiently at first

im = complex(0,1)
n = 244      
kdots = 1575      


def quantity_abs_squared(Vecs, Evalue, Eigen, rx,ry):
    holder = 0
    
    for k in range(0,kdots):
        
        for i in range(0,n):

                ind_G2a = G2*hexind[i,0] #G1, G2 are fixed (1,2) vectors
                ind_G1a = G1*hexind[i,1] #hexind is a list of (1,2) tuples of length n

                vectora = Vecs[k][:,i]    #Vecs has shape (1575, 244, 244) 

                wavea = np.exp(im*(ind_G1a[0] + ind_G2a[0])*rx + im*(ind_G1a[1] + ind_G2a[1])*ry)


            for j in range(0,n):

                ind_G2b = G2*hexind[j,0]
                ind_G1b = G1*hexind[j,1]

                # Extracting the eigenvector for the eigenvalues

                vectorb = Vecs[k][:,j]

                waveb = np.exp(im*(ind_G1b[0] + ind_G2b[0])*rx + im*(ind_G1b[1] + ind_G2b[1])*ry)

                coeffs = np.dot(vectora, np.conjugate(vectorb))

                exps = np.dot(wavea, np.conjugate(waveb))

                # For every kdots, there are n number of Eigenvalues
                # For every kdots, there are n number of Eigenvectors of length n

                holder = holder + coeffs*exps*delta((Egrid - Eigen[k][i]))

    quant = holder
    
    return (2*2)*quant/kdots
```

EDIT:

I have an idea but I am not sure how to bring it to fruition. The most important thing to get rid of is the combinations of the array `hexind` which is (n,2) in shape and holds the numbers that I need to multiply the `G1` and `G2` vectors with. Well what if I do something like this:

```py
differences = hexind.reshape([n, 1, 2])-hexind.reshape([1,n,2])
```

`differences` is now a (n,n,2) matrix that holds the index needed for the `G1` and `G2` part BUT also gives me the difference that I can input inside of the exponential. Again I am not sure how to loop through this matrix without for loops.

EDIT #2:

Typing out a minimal reproducible example. Let us say index is the following array:

```py
G1 = np.random.rand((1,2))
G2 = np.random.rand((1,2))

index = np. array([[ 0,  0],
       [ 1,  1],
       [ 1,  0],
       [ 0, -1],
       [-1, -1],
       [-1,  0],
       [ 0,  1]])
```

I then change this index in the following way:

```py
hexind2 = np.repeat(index,2, axis=0)   # repeat two times for every row
hexind = np.tile(hexind2,(2,1))
```

Then we can just create some random numpy arrays for the eigenvalues and eigenvectors:

```py
kdots = 100
n = 28

E = np.random.rand(100, n)
vec = np.random.rand(100,n,n) + 1j*np.random.rand(100,n,n)
```

Finally I call the function `quantity_abs_squared` as such:

```py
Eval = 300

rx = np.linspace(-20, 20)
ry = np.linspace(-20, 20)

Rx,Ry = np.meshgrid(rx,ry)

result = np.zeros((len(Rx), len(Ry)))


result = quantity_abs_squared(vec, Eval, E, Rx,Ry)
```

Comment: `vectorize` means replace one or more of the loops with multidimensional `numpy` methods and indexing.  In your case I'd start trying to `vectorize` the inner `j` loop.  What works or not if you use `hexind[:,0]`,`Vecs[k,:,:]`.  You may need to replace the `np.dot` calls with `matmul` or `einsum`.  `np.exp` can handle arrays just fine.  What's this `delta` call?  If you 'vectorize' the `j` loop, then you have chance at tackling the `i` and later the `k` loops.  You just have to work at it step by step.  There isn't a magic (no thought required) method.

Comment: @hpaulj Indeed I would basically be satisfied by vectorizing the `j` loop since without it the, the whole operation takes around 60 seconds, but with it is too long. I will check the `matmul` and `einsum` out, and I will upload the delta function, sorry I forgot to include it.

Comment: For a starter, move all `j`-independent variables out of the `j` loop. `matmul` is most certainly equivalent with `dot`. Also, it's better to do `Vecs[k,:,j]` than `Vecs[k][:,j]`.

Comment: We will more willing to help if you provide a [mcve], that is, a set of small arrays that are enough to run and test this code, any attempts to improve it.  I, for one, would copy your code to a `ipython` session, and run it.  Then start making tweaks, from inside out, making sure each worked right.

Comment: @hapulj Will do! Just give me some minutes thank you.

Comment: `im*(ind_G1b[0] + ind_G2b[0])*rx` -> `im` is not defined in your code.

Comment: It is defined as complex(0,1), I will add that